# Google Apps Scripts Send automated email with trigger (not repetitively)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I'm attempting to set up automated emails through google sheets using scripts and a trigger.

How do I define only new additions to the spreadsheet should trigger an email? The spreadsheet is constantly added to.

```
function sendloggeremails() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var lr = ss.getLastRow()

  for (var i = 72; i <= lr; i++) {
    var currentEmail = ss.getRange(i, 7).getValue();
    var currentClassTitle = ss.getRange(i, 3).getValue();

    MailApp.sendEmail(currentEmail, "complaint: customer number " + currentClassTitle ,  "Please check through the log as you have a new assigned to you");
  }
}
```

`var i = 72` plainly because this is the last row, I don't want to have to manually change this constantly. Added triggers but at the moment I still need to go into the code to change `var i`.

Any chance anyone can help with this?

Comment: To clarify, when you say 'new additions' do you mean another row is filled? Are the rows always added to the end? If you're always getting only the last row, the loop is unnecessary. If the cells are always filled from left to right, you could have the code only execute once the right-most cell has been filled.

Answer (score 0):

## Sending Emails only Once with a Loop

You could use something like this.  To get started you would want to put something in the sent column so that old lines would not resend their emails and you'd still maintain a record of past emails. I suggested putting the string "SENT".  But the test just ask the question is that column empty so anything will work.

Obviously, I haven't seen you spreadsheet so I don't know where to put the sentColumn so you can change the var sentColumn = 75 to anything you wish and all of the other places it's used will change accordingly.

```
function sendloggeremails() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();//You should probably change this to getSheetByName() and then put in the correct name of the sheet
  var sentColumn=75;//If this column is not empty then don't send emails.  If you send any email then also put "SENT" into this column so you wont resend it next time you run the loop.
  sh.getRange(1,sentColumn).setValue("Sent");//I'm assuming a header row and I'm putting a Header Title there you can pick any open column you want
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();//This gets all of the sheets data into one one range
  var vA=rg.getValues();//This gets all of the values in above range in a two dimension object we often refer to as a two dimensional array.
  //If you have header row you can start at i=1
  for(var i=1;i<vA.length; i++) {//This will loop over all of the rows on the sheet.
    if(!vA[i][sentColumn-1]){//Heres the test to see if theres something in sentColumn.  If sentColumn is empty meaning truthy is false then it send the email
      var currentEmail=vA[i][6];//this replaces the getValue from column7 *1
      var currentClassTitle=vA[i][2];//this replaces the getValue from column3 *1
      MailApp.sendEmail(currentEmail, "complaint: customer number " + currentClassTitle ,  "Please check through the log as you have a new assigned to you");
      sh.getRange(i+1,sentColumn).setValue("SENT");//After sending email we put something.  In this case "SENT" into the sentColumn so that next through the loop we won send another email because its truthy will be true.
    }
  }
}
//*1 Array indices are 1 less that column numbers because arrays start counting from zero.
```

If you wish we could also delete the rows as we send them. All you have to do is keep track of how many rows you have deleted each time the loop is run with say a variable like var n=0 to start with and then the row number that gets deleted will be i-n+1. And right after the deletion you increment n by one.

You can setup the trigger using this function.

```
function setupEmailTrigger() {  
  if(ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().indexOf('sendloggeremails')==-1){
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('sendloggeremails').timeBased().everyDays(1).atHour(17).create();
  }
}
```

It checks to see if the trigger already exists and if the trigger already exists it does nothing.